# Is it possible to have more types of Haki in One Piece?

Tags: one-piece

Haki is the mysterious power of spiritual energy in *One Piece*. As an example, Busoshoku Haki can allow users to convert spiritual energy into armor.

Luffy can generate fire in a red hawk attack, it may be a type of Haki that allows users to generate fire from spiritual energy.  Similarly, Sanji, Zoro, and Kin'emon can generate fire. Kaido and Yamato can generate lightning using Haki.

Comment: while im not well informed on one piece a [quick google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Is+it+possible+to+have+more+types+of+Haki+in+One+Piece%3F&rlz=1CAQIMT_enUS936&oq=Is+it+possible+to+have+more+types+of+Haki+in+One+Piece%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i61&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&safe=active&ssui=on) says that it *is* possibleto possess more than one type of haki, and luffy has all three types

Comment: @ᴅᴀɴɪᴇʟ I don't believe OP is asking about whether an individual can have more than one of the existing three types of haki but rather could there be more than three types. I can't recall a lot of the examples given but I am pretty sure Sanji's Diable Jambe doesn't involve haki, its just heat from friction. Friction rendering one's leg red hot is pretty wacky but One Piece has plenty of this, Fishman Karate is basically waterbending and the entire Rokushiki stable of techniques are pretty out there and none of which involve haki

Comment: @Gatchwar Red hawk may be a heat from friction, but what you will say about thunder Bagua of Yamato and kaido... they are generating lightning from their haki, we have also seen the lightning effect of Haki whenever 2 king Haki user clash each other....

Comment: I think Luffy's attacks can use any characteristic that he can imagine..... integrating with Haki is something else.

Answer (score 1):

There are three types of Haki:

1. Observation Haki
2. Armament Hardening
3. Conquerors Haki

Luffy has all. So yes, one can have more than one type.

Comment: my question is Busoshoku Haki can allow users to convert spiritual energy into armor. so it is possible to create other elements like lightning and fire using Busoshoku Haki... for example red hawk, thunder bagua

Comment: I don't see how it would be possible. Nothing in the story indicates that you can use this haki to create other elements. It's just armor. @SayedMohdAli

Comment: @pushkin In many other animes, you can convert spiritual energy into other elements as well. Haki is spiritual energy nothing else.